# Caching error in parallel python

Tags: parallel-processing, python-2.7, parallel-python

I am having a problem with the transparent caching when using the parallel python module. I changed a method signature in a module called by my parallelized code. When I execute the code it gives me an error saying it expected the old method signature.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ppworker.py", line 90, in run
    __result = __f(*__args)
  File "<string>", line 12, in run_grn
TypeError: __init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

I deleted the .pyc files in case it was using them and still no joy. When I renamed the module to something else it started working again, so I can only assume that parallel python is storing an old copy of the module somewhere. I checked the documentation but it doesn't mention anything about how the caching works. Is there any way to clear the cache? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Update: After a bit of digging I found it made a copy of my file in the dist-packages folder and it was not overwriting it (possibly because of permissions). When I deleted the file it, fixed the problem